# C# Inline if statement returns wrong type

Tags: c#, types

I'm creating a Json parser in a single file, while parsing ints and doubles I got an error that a double was returned while I used `int.Parse(num)`.

I checked it with this: `((true ? int.Parse(num) : double.Parse(num)).GetType().Name` and this for some reason returns a double even though there shouldn't be a way for it do return that.

My leading theory is that C# really likes it's types, a 1 is valid inside an int and a double, but a 1.1 is only valid in a double so it chooses the double even though the return type is "object".

Example:

```cs
function object ParseValue(string num)
{
    return true ? int.Parse(num) : double.Parse(num)
}

ParseValue("1").GetType().Name > Double
```

If you have another possible theory please do share.

Comment: Both sides of a ternary expression must have the same type so if you have `int : double` then the int is promoted to a double.

Comment: The return type of the method is not considered when deciding on the type of the ternary

Answer (score 2):

This is the expected and only possible behaviour. The ternary operator cannot return two different types from the same expression. Both expressions must either be the same type or one must be assignable to the other. In this case, `int` is assignable to `double` so it is `double` that the expression returns. Try using that operator with two types that are completely incompatible and the compiler will choke on it for that very reason. If you want two different types then you would have to actually use an `if`/`else` block.

If you think of the ternary operator as a method - it's not but there enough similarities for this purpose - then it would look something like this:

```cs
T Ternary<T>(bool input, T output1, T output2)
{
    if (input)
    {
        return output1;
    }

    return output2;
}
```

If you were to call that method and pass an `int` and a `double` as arguments, `T` would be inferred as `double` and the `int` would be converted to that type, because both outputs have to be the same type and the alternative might lose data.

Comment: Yea I know so my theory was correct, I'm currently using an if/else block. Thank you for confirming though

Answer (score 2):

Ternary operator can return one type only, so you can cast values to `object`: if `value` can be parsed to `int` we return boxed `int`, otherwise boxed `double`:

```
private static object ParseValue(string value) => 
    int.TryParse(value, out int intValue) ? (object) intValue
  : (object) double.Parse(value);
```

You can elaborate it into more types, if you like:

```
private static object ParseValue(string value) => 
    bool.TryParse(value, out bool bValue) ? (object) bValue
  : int.TryParse(value, out int iValue) ? (object) iValue
  : double.TryParse(value, out double dValue) ? (object) dValue
  : DateTime.TryParseExact(value, 
      CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.RFC1123Pattern, 
      default, 
      DateTimeStyles.None, 
      out DateTime dtValue) ? (object)dtValue
  : (object) value;
```

here we try parse into `bool`, `int`, `double`, `DateTime` (in this order up to the first success), and if all options are failed, return original string